# Animations in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

How can I create such "animations" or custom transitions between views in UIPageViewController as you can see in this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0395LXtwCBfQ3N4eEJ6cnQtQms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I didn't mention that in my answer, but it's not a `UIPageViewController`, it's a regular scroll view with paging enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIScrollView` is your friend.
You have to set your scrollView's delegate and listen to the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method.

There's no magic code, and you must do the transitions yourself, like placing elements or set opacity depending on the the scroll view's `contentOffset`.

Some other effects uses the `mask` property of a `CALayer` to make the first transition like the round icon which transforms to a rectangular card.

As a sample project :https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands

Comment: do you have-see any sample project on github or anywhere else. I'm also want to do something like this but uipageviewController doesn't let tranforming button from one page to other. Scrollview is right but it is so tricky. A sample  can be great. ty!